# JDBC implementation: How to write Java functions for stored procedures that use Inner Join's

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am working on creating a JDBC program that will show a list of grades that a selected student has in their respective classes. However, I am having diffficulty understanding how to implement my stored procedure via Java, as it makes use of inner joins.

Here is my stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[getStudentHistory]

@studentId INT
AS
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Year, Term, C.Prefix + ' ' + CAST(C.Num AS CHAR(3)) + ' - ' + SEC.Letter AS [Course Number], 
            Units, isNull(G.Letter, ' ') AS Grade
FROM Student S

 INNER JOIN StudentInSection SIS
    ON S.StudentId = SIS.StudentId
 INNER JOIN Section SEC
    ON SEC.SectionId = SIS.SectionId
 INNER JOIN Course C
    ON C.CourseId = SEC.CourseId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade G
    ON G.GradeId = SIS.GradeId
 INNER JOIN Semester SEM
    ON SEM.SemesterId = SEC.SemesterId

WHERE S.StudentId = @studentId
Order BY Units DESC
```

Here is my function within my Main Class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")

public static void showStudentHistory()

{

System.out.print("\n Please enter the Id of a current student you wanna see grades for");
System.out.print("\n==>");

Scanner insertstudentID = new Scanner(System.in);
int passedStudentID = insertstudentID.nextInt() ;

Student student = new Student(passedStudentID, null, null);
List<Student> students =  student.getStudentHistory(passedStudentID);
String tabs = "\t\t";
System.out.println("LastName"+ tabs + "FirstName"+ tabs + "Year"+ tabs + "Term"+ tabs + "Course Number"+ tabs + "Units"+ tabs + "Grade");
System.out.println("---------"+ tabs + "---------"+ tabs + "--------"+ tabs + "-----------");


//            Student tempStu = students.get(passedStudentID);
//            System.out.println(tempStu.getmStudentId() + "\t\t\t" +
//                    padRight(tempStu.getmFirstName(), 15) + "\t\t" +
//                    padRight(tempStu.getmLastName(), 15) + "\t\t" +
//                    tempStu.getmNum());

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\nHit Enter to continue...");
String discard = kb.nextLine();
```

And here is the accompanying function in my Student Class:

```
public List<Student> getStudentHistory(int StudentID) {

   List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
   Connection con = dbConnect();
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   try {
       ps = con.prepareCall("getStudentHistory");
       rs = ps.executeQuery();
       // Iterate through the data in the result set and load the List
//             while (rs.next()) {
//                 students.add(new Student(rs.getInt("StudentId")
//                         , rs.getString("LastName")
//                         , rs.getString("FirstName")
//                         , rs.getInt("Year")
//                         , rs.getString("Course Number")
//                         , rs.getInt("Units")
//                         , rs.getString("Grade")
//                         )                                                   
//                         );
//             }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
           if (ps != null) try { ps.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
           if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
       }
       return students;

}
```

Also, here is the constructor of my Student Class:

```
public class Student {
    private int mStudentId;
    private String mLastName;
    private String mFirstName;
    private int mNum;

// Provide an empty constructor
public Student(int i, String string, String string2) {
}
```

I know that my stored procedure works fine by itself in SQL Server, but I am getting confused with how I can properly implement a stored proc within Java that has inner joins. All of my other stored procedures for creating, updating, deleting, and displaying Student data function fine, but they only make use of a single Student table.

If you look in my main class, I have commented out a set of code that I used to output the 4 attributes of the Student class onto the screen for a different function. In order to do this, there are get functions that were defined with respect to the constructor. I could redefine my constructor to include additional values so that I can make get functions for other variables, but that would change the order in which my variables, appear. That would make the rest of my code fail, as it would make other functions call the wrong variables. I started to do this, but then realized that my display function was returning all sorts of wrong variable because I had changed the order.

I would appreciate any pointers that the community can give me, and I'd be happy to post more of my code if anyone thinks it would be relevant to finding a solution to my problem.

Comment: You simply have to handle the columns in the result set in the order the procedure provides them in.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what you mean by that? If you could give me even a simple example it would help me understand what you're trying to teach me.

Comment: What does "functions that were defined with respect to the constructor" mean? In the code snippet I see one constructor for `Student`, which does nothing and is not used in the code. Anyway, I guess the confusion is that you want to squeeze results from several tables, which represent different things, into a single object. `getStudentHistory` should not return a list of `Student` but something like a list of `StudentGrades` (a class to be written which contains the courses and the grades for the given student)

Comment: public int getmStudentId() {
        return mStudentId;
    }

    public String getmLastName() {
        return mLastName;
    }

    public void setmLastName(String mLastName) {
        this.mLastName = mLastName;
    }

    public String getmFirstName() {
        return mFirstName;
    }

    public void setmFirstName(String mFirstName) {
        this.mFirstName = mFirstName;
    }

    public int getmNum() {
        return mNum;
    }

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should create a new class called Student Grades, and create the getStudentHistory function inside of this class?

Comment: Yes, I think you should create a new class and make `getStudentHistory` return a list of these objects. Not sure if `getStudentHistory` method itself should be inside that class, but that is a matter of taste.